# Transforming a DIV

Tags: html, css

(Originally : To transform or not to transform)

I wanted to start spinning the DIV box so it would spin behind the text boxes. BECAUSE the text boxes did not seem to care what I did with the DIV I just made the javascript spin the DIV. To my surprise - by spinning the DIV the text boxes spun with the DIV and when they went outside of the DIV boxes area - they are now clipped. If I comment out the transforms the text boxes go back to ignoring anything I do with the DIV. So ideas why it is doing this? Do I maybe have to always do a transform and just set the degrees to zero(0)? Ideas and comments are welcome. :-) Here is the code:

PS: I put in the BODY's "overflow:hidden;" because I was testing that out too. Just a FYI. :-)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
.p1 {   position:absolute;
                top:50px;
                left:50px;
                border: 1px solid grey;
                padding: 5px;
                font-family: sans-serif,Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,"Trebuchet MS",Tahoma,"MS Sans Serif",Geneva;
                font-size: 12pt;
                width: 150px;
                height: 10pt;
                overflow: hidden;
                z-index:0;
            }
</style>
</head>
<body style='overflow:hidden;'>
<div id='d1' name='d1' style="width:500px;height:400px;overflow:hidden;z-index:1;
    border:1px solid black;clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);clip:rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);">
<p id='p1' name='p1' class='p1'>This is a test of how HTML works</p>
<p id='p2' name='p2' class='p1'>This is a test of how HTML works</p>
<p id='p3' name='p3' class='p1'>This is a test of how HTML works</p>
</div>
<script>
function moveIt(n)
{
    document.getElementById("p1").style.left = n;
    document.getElementById("p2").style.top = n;
    document.getElementById("p3").style.left = n;
    document.getElementById("p3").style.top = n;
//  document.getElementById("d1").style.transform = "rotate(" + n + "deg)";
    if( n < 2000 ){ setTimeout("moveIt(" + (n + 1) + ")", 1 ); }
        else { moveIt2(n); }
}
function moveIt2(n)
{
    document.getElementById("p1").style.left = n;
    document.getElementById("p2").style.top = n;
    document.getElementById("p3").style.left = n;
    document.getElementById("p3").style.top = n;
//  document.getElementById("d1").style.transform = "rotate(" + n + "deg)";
    if( n > -1000 ){ setTimeout("moveIt2(" + (n - 1) + ")", 1 ); }
        else { moveIt(n); }
}
    moveIt(50);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me say, up front, that if you put the transform in with a 0deg rotation that the postiion:absolute works.  So it seems like something is not applying the transform IF you don't put it in and this is what seems to affect what is going on.  Further testing needs to be done.  Also, be sure to see the "To transform or not to transform" question where someone has already said to use the position:relative.  Which also works.  Last, the reason this is here is because Jon P asked that I split it up.  Quote: You have two questions here. Please separate them into two unique questions. –  Jon P

Answer (score 0):

A CSS transform on a parent element affects all the parent's children.  That's why the text rotates.

You can prevent their rotation by applying a negative rotation equal in amount to the parent's positive rotation.

Also:  You need to supply units such as `px` when setting the position of elements, like this:

```
document.getElementById('p1').style.left = n + 'px';
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wuLshrqn/)

Comment: *[not] Working Fiddle* `:)`

Comment: @abforce, did I misinterpret the OP's question?

Comment: OP  does not want text elements to rotate (become fixed), but in your fiddle those perform a uniform dance!

Comment: Ahh, I canceled their 360° rotation, but they *do* travel with their parent (in addition to their own movement).

Comment: @MarkManning, can you clarify what the expected behavior is?  You could take the text out of the div to prevent its rotation from affecting them.  But I assumed there was a reason for them being inside it.

Comment: The original intent was to have the text boxes slide off and disappear as they left the DIV box (the larger box).  Without the transform absolute positioning does NOT honor the boundaries of the DIV box.  First solution (on the other question) was to use position:relative to make this happen.  However, I found that if you used the transform statement that THEN the position:absolute would work also.  My posting of wanting to spin the DIV box was because the smaller text boxes were ignoring the DIV box even though they were children of the DIV box.  Clearer?

Comment: A transform is similar to `position: relative` in that the absolute-positioned children are affected by their spinning parent.  However, transform is different from `position: relative` in that it ignores `overflow: hidden`.  You can have both transform *and* `position: relative`, and then `overflow: hidden` will be honored.

Comment: If you want the box to spin without appearing to affect its children, the children will need to have an equal and opposite transform, which is difficult math since each child has its own line box.